# Can minutes be used to measure the length?

Tags: notation, unit-of-measure

I am using an Old American maths textbook and it uses US customary units. For the length, they use minutes (like $6'$ for the altitude of a triangle). How is this related to foot which is the unit of length in US customary units? This seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: Probably on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: Im Canadian but i have done some engineering and physics so i think i know what your talking about and i thought that the unit in minutes was the angle in the bottom corner of a right angle triangle so it applies to any length.

Comment: At the Equator $1$ minute of arc is about $1$ nautical mile.

Comment: i think its something funny like 30 degrees + 6 hours + 6 minutes is like 30 + 6/60 + 6/3600 = 30.102 degrees or something then u just put it on a triangle n extrapolate any length you want by making a triangle with 1 unit of length as one side and that angle u can then solver for each amount of unit of length then put in your favorite method of measuring stuff.

Comment: ' is a symbol for a foot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the old Imperial measures, still used in the US, ' means feet and '' means inches (12 inches to the foot).

Comment: how did u figure out that's what he was asking?! lol

Answer (score 2):

$6'$ as a length would mean $6$ feet.

A minute is usually a measure of time ($1/60$th of an hour) but can also be a measure of angle ($1/60$th of a degree).  As an angle $6$ minutes would also be written $6'$, but it doesn't uniquely specify a length.